# MySQL from Deb changing configuration after installing perl packages?

Tags: mysql, debian, debian-wheezy

This will sound silly, I'm sure. Here goes.

I have a new installation of Debian Wheezy (Debian7).
Instead of going with the aptitude installation of MySQL that right now holds v5.5.31 I went with the deb-package from MySQL to get the latest stable release (currently 5.6.15).

After a little tweaking and adding of my.cnf it worked fine. All was well.
However, I wanted to utilize some statistics tools that rely on Perl, so I did the following

```
sudo aptitude install libdbi-perl
sudo aptitude install libdbd-mysql-perl
```

Having done that, I now get the following error when trying to start MySQL:

```
service mysql start
Starting MySQL
[FAIL] Couldn't find MySQL server (/usr/bin/mysqld_safe) ... failed!
```

This is really peculiar to me since I have mysql installed in the default dir for deb-packages i.e. /opt/mysql/server-5.6/ and before the installation of perl DBI and mysql-support for perl it all was working just fine. Did the perl-mysql bindings screw with some global configurations? I don't have the /usr/bin/mysqld_safe path set anywhere that I know of.

Any help at all would be great. Thanks

EDIT:

Well, it was silly indeed.

If you are every in the same situation, just do this

```
sudo rm /etc/mysql -R
```

It shouldn't be necessary as the documenation from MySQL clearly states that it looks for my.cnf in /etc/my.cnf or in the /opt/mysql/server-5.6/my.cnf location and **not in /etc/mysql/my.cnf**. Clearly this is **not so** since it used the /etc/mysql/my.cnf in my case. Removing it did the trick.

Comment: When you installed libdbd-mysql-perl, did the system by any chance mention something about installing any other required packages? Such as maybe mysql?

Comment: Not that I could see. It did complain a lot about locales and stuff and I had to set the locale using locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 and 
dpkg-reconfigure locales in order for perl to stop complaining. Other than that it was smooth sailing.

Comment: re-installing the perl packages I see that it installs mysql-common (which basically puts /etc/mysql/conf.d/.keepme
/etc/mysql/my.cnf there but the deb pkg installation reads my.cnf from /etc/my.cnf not /etc/mysql/my.cnf from what I can see)